# Find URL of Active or current tab opened on chromium or find out if a particular tab is opened

Tags: python, linux, selenium, shell, google-chrome

I want to find out if a particular tab is opened on chromium.I tried with the below query in terminal "I got No such file". I verrified Current Session does not exist

```
strings ~/'.config/chromium/Default/Current Session' | 'grep' -E 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/'
```

I tried with selenium as well but it shows only for the chrome window which it has opened, I want to know if that tab is opened on any chrome window

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, )

driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

tabs_list = []
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(handle)
    tabs_list.append(driver.current_url)

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
for tab in tabs_list:
    if url in tab:
        print('found')
```

Am new to this.
Please help me out to find particular tab is opened on chromium or to get active tab url, operating system is Linux based

Thank You

Comment: There's not enough detail here to be sure, but given the error my first suspicion is the arguments you have for `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, )`. Can you provide the full text of the error?  Also, I'm a little confused--you are navigating to google and expecting to find multiple open windows?

Comment: Also, I noticed the space in `Current Session` -- I think that needs to be handled differently

Comment: @peck with selenium I don't have any errors.. with the command which I give in terminal am getting no such file.. Current session doesn't exist in default directory... both of them are two different approaches which I have tried

Comment: Can you please paste the full text of the "No Such File" error you are experiencing? You said with selenium you don't have any errors, but does it work? If not how not?

Comment: @C.Peck  Please check out
strings: '/home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Current Session': No such file.

In selenium it work's only for the chrome window which it has opened, I want it to work not only when it is opened by seleneium even if  chrome is opened with other means then also it should work